# Add Key => Value to PHP Array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to add the key 'username' with the value of 'johnsmith' to each array but have been unable to get it working.

Here's the code that is generating the array:

```
foreach($rows as $row)
    {
    $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
```

Here is the array output:

```
[0] => Array (
    [Date] => 4/22/2018
    [Calories Burned] => 3,178
    [Steps] => 9,966
    [Distance] => 4.86
    [Floors] => 8
    [Minutes Sedentary] => 762
    [Minutes Lightly Active] => 204
    [Minutes Fairly Active] => 79
    [Minutes Very Active] => 51
    [Activity Calories] => 1,778
    )
[1] => Array (
    [Date] => 4/23/2018
    [Calories Burned] => 3,284
    [Steps] => 9,671
    [Distance] => 4.69
    [Floors] => 9
    [Minutes Sedentary] => 805
    [Minutes Lightly Active] => 180
    [Minutes Fairly Active] => 101
    [Minutes Very Active] => 68
    [Activity Calories] => 1,903
    )
[2] => Array (
    [Date] => 4/24/2018
    [Calories Burned] => 3,714
    [Steps] => 12,312
    [Distance] => 5.92
    [Floors] => 6
    [Minutes Sedentary] => 676
    [Minutes Lightly Active] => 239
    [Minutes Fairly Active] => 131
    [Minutes Very Active] => 84
    [Activity Calories] => 2,462
    )
```

I tried the following code, but it just overwrites the array:

```
   $csv += [ "username" => johnsmith ];
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Tim

Comment: `$row['username'] = "johnsmith"` before you add it to `$csv[] = $row;`. (don't know if you need `$header` still then)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you build the array

```
$headers[] = 'username'; //add the key to the end of your headers

foreach($rows as $row){
    $row[] = 'johnsmith'; //add value to the end of the row.
    //now combine them.
    $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}
```

One word of caution is `array_combine` will get you here, both arrays have to be the same length.  So by changing `$row` you are adding something that may not be in header if header does not have username you have to add it.

You also **probably** want to keep the `$header` in sync with the `$csv` sub-arrays.  It makes life easier latter on.

When you combine them (to explain)

```
 $headers = [
    "Date",
    "Calories Burned",
    "Steps",
    "Distance",
    "Floors",
    "Minutes Sedentary",
    "Minutes Lightly Active",
    "Minutes Fairly Active",
    "Minutes Very Active",
    "Activity Calories"
 ];


$row = [
    "4/23/2018",
    "3,284",
    "9,671",
    "4.69",
    "9",
    "805",
    "180",
    "101",
    "68",
    "1,903"
];
```

These combine fine, but if you add

```
$row = [
    "4/23/2018",
    "3,284",
    "9,671",
    "4.69",
    "9",
    "805",
    "180",
    "101",
    "68",
    "1,903",
    "username" => "johnsmith"
];
```

You will get an error when combining this with `$headers` because the `$row` is 1 longer then the `$headers`.  But, if you add the header at the end, then add the data to the end of the row. Everything is fine again, because they are the same length.

Array combine is a great function, but it can be a bit nasty to work with.

**A word of caution:**

Other solutions may add the data in, but think what happens **if** you go to make a CSV file of this.  Because they have not modified the header row. when you do

```
   fputcsv($f, $header);
```

your header is going to be one short.

If you are just reading a CSV file, then the you may be OK not changing the headers.  But remember if you use them (the headers) for anything else they will be out of sync with your data.

For example: Even when reading you could use that header row for the columns in a table to display the data, you will find yourself one header short.

Based solely on how you are naming your varaibles it looks like you are probably pulling data from a database and creating a CSV file from it?  I could be wrong in this, but if this is the case you can short cut a bit more.

**AS a Bonus**

```
  header('Content-Type: application/csv');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.csv');
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  $f = fopen('php://output'); //PHP stream wrapper

  $headers[] = 'username';

  fputcsv($f, $headers);

  foreach($rows as $row){
    $row[] = 'johnsmith'; //add value to the end of the row.
    fputcsv($f, $row);
  }
```

What this does, is skip making a separate array, and a "real" file.

It has several advantages and one disadvantage

Advantages

- No extra arrays
- No extra file to delete
- Download larger files because it streams the data to the browser
- Shorter code

Disadvantage

- No download progress bar, because you don't know the size of the file being made

If you are not doing that, you can probably use it elsewhere.

One of the main things I do at my job is create CSV files, I work with them on a daily basis.  So I have about 5 years experience reading and writing them.  This is how I know this.

Cheers!

Comment: You can downvote but you obviously have no idea how `array_combine` works.

Comment: That's a solution too. An additional header is added and a respective value is added to the row.

Comment: I love how after I point this out all the answers change... lmao.

Comment: @Rinsad Ahmed it's the only solution.

Comment: How comes its the only solution? Did you try my solution? It will work fine as yours even Roman Hocke's solution will work

Comment: Because if/when they go to write a csv file from this their headers will get put at the top of the file, and they will be one short.  Now if they are just reading a CSV the other solutions may work, but if they use the header array for anything it's out of sync with the data.

Comment: @RinsadAhmed - please don't take it the wrong way, I'm just saying in the greater context of things.  Doing it another way may cause other issues down the road.  I have a ton of experience working with CSV files, so I can see the larger scope of what is going on, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to insert it to every row separately:

```
foreach($rows as $row) {

    $csv[] = array_merge(
        array_combine($header, $row),
        array('username' => $johnsmith, 'anything' => 'else')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I always like a solution that modifies the existing code as little as possible, so here is mine:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row) + ["username" => "johnsmith"];
}
```

Explanation: just add any additional values as an array to the result of `array_combine()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
   foreach($rows as $row) {
     $newArray=array_combine($header, $row);
     $newArray["username"]="johnsmith";
     $csv[] = $newArray;
   }
```